# Change A5 to A4 format on runtime

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I created a A5 report in ireport and use in java application.
I change A5 to A4 format on runtime and View Page but when print Page output be A5 format.

following code:

```
        JasperDesign _des = JRXmlLoader.load("report1.jrxml");

        _des.setPageHeight(842);
        _des.setPageWidth(595);

        JasperReport _rep = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(_des);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(_rep, params, _data);

        JRViewer_com = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);
```

Comment: That actually looks correct to me. We do something similar without any problems. So it is hard to help. What version of JasperReports are you using?

Comment: jasperReports-4.1.3,jasper-conpiler-jdt-5.5.15

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of JasperReports. Maybe it is a bug, we currently are using 4.5, and I think they are up to 5 now.

Comment: I upgrade to 4.5 but not work correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something missing in your code that is not supplied in your question. When I created an example and ran it it works. The only change I made was I used the static method `JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);` to view the report.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Test\\src\\report1.jrxml");
    System.out.println("file = "+file.exists());
    JasperDesign _des = JRXmlLoader.load(file);

    _des.setPageHeight(842);
    _des.setPageWidth(595);

    JasperReport _rep = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(_des);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(_rep, new HashMap<String, Object>());
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);
}
```

If you could provide a small single java class that is runnable and reproduces the issue, I may be able to help more.